# Unable to install Ubuntu 22.04 on NUC11 PAHi50001

Tags: software-installation, intel-nuc

I have installed Ubuntu on an Intel NUC. I have changed some BIOS settings. My main display was showing text cut off. After I restart my machine, I don't see the Ubuntu OS loaded at all.

[image]

Comment: Maybe tell which settings you changed?